# Stat vs ftell performance for calculating single large file size in C

Tags: c

I have few large xml files that I open, read and then write to another file.

To skip empty xml file reads, I am using fseek and ftell to get the file size and comparing for zero bytes. the file size is roughly around 2MB. How does fseek+ftell impact performance compared to stat in this case?

TIA.

Comment: Can't you measure this yourself? Some simple profiling will give you the answer.

Comment: Why aren't you doing `int fd = fileno( filePtr ); fstat( fd, &statBuf );` instead of `stat( filename, &statBuf );`?

Comment: You didn't give any specifics on your environment, system, cpu speed. For example, on a modern, high end PC,  As @ForceBru says, you should do some profiling as everything we say hear is conjecture in the end.

Comment: It would at-least-seem straightforward that you already have a harness (your program) in place to determine this for your specific conditions? Just replace your fseek/ftell logic with stat and profile the differences. Unless you're doing this many *many* times in short succession, I sincerely doubt it will make a difference either way.

Comment: 2MB is nothing these days and the performance difference is likely to be minimal and configuration dependent. If numbers get huge, statting a file is a little bit safer than trying to seek the end and ftelling.